# How to use Thinktecture Identity Manager with AspNetIdentity

Tags: c#, user-management, asp.net-identity

Does anyone have a working sample of how to use Identity Manager in ASP.NET MVC, using AspNetIdentity?

The Github documentation is outdated and so are the code samples on the website.

Thanks

Comment: Why use this outdated tool? Looking at codeplex and GitHub this seems to be a dead project. The sample template from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples) has all features you need basically. Other features are easy to add if you would really need them....

Comment: Thanks  - it's technically still supposed to be supported. They should honestly take the site down or put a notice up, NOT DEAD, need your contribution. Disappointing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer - don't use Thinktecture Identity Manager!

For those looking to have user management in MVC 5 with Asp.Net identity, these might help:

- [ASP.NET Identity 2.0: Customizing Users and Roles](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/790720/ASP-NET-Identity-Customizing-Users-and-Roles)
- [Asp.Net Identity Sample (as mentioned)](https://github.com/rustd/AspnetIdentitySample)
- [Building a CMS With ASP.NET MVC5](http://code.tutsplus.com/courses/building-a-cms-with-aspnet-mvc5)

Comment: Any reason not to use it?

Comment: Yip - they stopped supporting/working it, and as far as I'm aware it didn't work (at the time at least). Don't have more specifics as time has passed...

Comment: @AndriyF. oooh I see there are recent updates and PR's